# Cannot publish any task form in InfoPath 2013

Tags: 2010, infopath, tasks

In company we have SharePoint 2010 and InfoPath 2013. I create a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2010

I wanted to change approval form so I opened it with InfoPath. When I try to publish it I get this error:

> Infopath has encountered an error. The operation failed publish.

Error is shown even if I didn't change anything and I try to publish.

What is strange when I tried to publish it using different user account it worked few times. However now also in other user account it gets error.

Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath 2013 is working with SharePoint 2010 properly but you should specify **backward compatibility** by doing the following:

- Open your form.
- file > info > form options.
- at compatibility section > from for type drop-down list > select `web browser form (InfoPath 2010)`
  [image]

Comment: It's strange but I cannot change anything in compatibility section. It's all grayed out.

Comment: do you have any issue to install InfoPath 2010 beside 2013

Comment: Unfortunately installing anything in company's computer is a little problematic